# WordPress jQuery works on post but doesn't work on custom post type

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields, html5-audio

I have the strangest problem with my code and I've looked all over on how to solve it. What it does is it reads a locally uploaded file and get a duration and size. The problem I'm having is that it works perfectly on `post` except on a custom post type, where all except the duration. JS File in enqueued and works. Even if I inline the code with a metabox, it does the same thing: works on 'Posts", partially works on a custom post type.

On `posts` (i.e. `post-new.php`), if I upload a MP3 file locally (but not saving it to the library), it reads everything. I created a custom post type called 'episodes' and everything works except the duration.

This is what it looks like on `posts`

[image]

And this is what it looks like on a custom post type

[image]

This is what my JS code looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var objectUrl;
$("#audio").on("canplaythrough", function(e){
    var seconds = e.currentTarget.duration;
    var duration = moment.duration(seconds, "seconds");
    var hours = duration.hours();
    var mins = duration.minutes();
    var secs = duration.seconds();
    if (hours < 10) { time_hour = "0" + hours + ":" ; } else { time_hour = hours + ":" ;};
    if (mins < 10) { time_mins = "0" + mins + ":" ; } else { time_mins = mins + ":" ;};
    if (secs < 10) { time_secs = "0" + secs} else { time_secs = secs};
    $("#duration").text(time_hour+time_mins+time_secs);
    
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
});

$("#file").change(function(e){
    var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

    $("#filename").text(file.name);
    $("#filetype").text(file.type);
    $("#filesize").text(file.size);
    
    objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $("#audio").prop("src", objectUrl);
});
});
```

And this is my custom post function:

```
function episodes() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Episodes', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Episode', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Episodes', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Episodes', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Episode', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Podcast episodes', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-audio',
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'episodes', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'episodes', 0 );
```